# Java How to make a method that accepts two list types, not at the same time

Tags: java, list, methods

I have this piece of code

```
public void write(LinkedList<Drug> list, String file) {
    try (FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\res\\" + file + ".dat"); ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs)) {
        System.out.println("Writing File...");
        os.writeObject(list);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

what I want is to use the same method to write a file of a different object for example

```
LinkedList<String> temp = new LinkedList<>();
temp.add("Something");
temp.add("Something else");
write(temp, "stringlist");
```

and I don't want to just make a second method which will be

```
public void writeSomething(LinkedList<String> list, String file) {
    try (FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\res\\" + file + ".dat"); ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs)) {
        System.out.println("Writing File...");
        os.writeObject(list);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: *FYI (unrelated):* `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`, so you can drop that `catch (FileNotFoundException e)`. If it hadn't been and you want same logic, you could merge them using a multi-catch: `catch (IOException | SomeOtherException e)`.

Comment: I think  you didn't get the question

Comment: My comment is not an answer to your question. It is just an unrelated *comment*, trying to teach you better code.

Comment: @Andreas oh, thank you for the info, appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your method doesn't make use of type of objects stored in the list then you can declare your method as following:

```
public void writeSomething(LinkedList<?> list, String file)
```

Comment: Also perhaps worth pointing out that `List<?>` (or `Collection<?>` , or `Iterable<?>`) might be better than `LinkedList<?>` specifically (although you would need it to be `Serializable`, ofc)

Comment: @AndyTurner You could do `public <T extends List<?> & Serializable> void write(T list, String file)` to enforce that.

Comment: @Andreas yep, true!

Comment: @Andreas Since this method doesn't depend on any methods of `List` we can simplify it to `public void write(Serializable object, String file)`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question *literally* as stated - to allow the method to accept exactly 2 list types - have two methods which call a private generic method:

```
public void writeDrugs(LinkedList<Drug> list, String file) {
  writeGeneric(list, file);
}

public void writeStrings(LinkedList<String> list, String file) {
  writeGeneric(list, file);
}

private void writeGeneric(LinkedList<?> list, String file) {
  // Implementation here.
}
```

Note that your two public methods would need to be named differently, as otherwise they would have the same erasure.

Of course, if you don't care about it being just these two types, you can simply make the `writeGeneric` (or whatever your want to call it) method `public`.

Comment: Dang, wish you could use `|` like in a [multi-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) statement and say `public <E extends Drug | String> void writeStrings(LinkedList<E> list, String file)`, but you can only use `&`. :-(